# ant record task save to different directory

Tags: ant

I am looking for a way to change the directory to which the ant `record` task saves. Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
<record name="${logFileName}" action="start" append="true" loglevel="verbose" />
```

Currently using the example above, but i would like to save to a different directory than the one that is selected by default. Currently it just does the current working directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass an absolute file name rather than a relative one:

```
<record name="/home/prolink007/record.txt" action="start" append="true" loglevel="verbose" />
```

Comment: It worked. I was using another property for the `/home/prolink007` and i had not loaded the property yet. It is working now.